# Inserting multiple rows into MySQL with checkbox

Tags: php, mysql, web, checkbox, dreamweaver

Below is my code. I have two MySQL database tables, one is "member" and another one is "participants". I would like to display the data in table "member" to my local host page and I did it. However, I cannot insert multiple rows of "member" data by using checkbox to my database table "participants". I am stuck. Any help is much appreciated.

```
<?php
try {
    $con = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=kgruum member", "root", "");
    $sql = $con->query("SELECT * FROM member");
    echo "<table class='info' align='center' border='1'>";
    echo "<tr><td width='10'></td>
        <td width='10'><b>ID</b></td>
        <td width='500'><b>Name</b></td>
        <td width='50'><b>Handicap</b></td><tr>";

    foreach($sql as $row) {
        $ID = $row["ID"];
        $Name = $row["Name"];
        $Handicap = $row["Handicap"];
        echo "<tr>
            <td><form method='POST' action='Add participant.php'><input type='checkbox' name='insert[]' value='$ID'></td>
            <td>$ID</td>
            <td>$Name</td>
            <td>$Handicap</td><tr>";
    }

    echo"</table><div align='center'><input type='image' value='submit' src='add selected button.png' alt='submit Button' onmouseover='this.src='pink add selected button.png'' onmouseout='this.src='add selected button.png'' name='add_btn' id='add_btn'></div><br></form>";


    if(isset($_POST['add_btn'])) {
        if(!empty($_POST['insert'])) {
            foreach($_POST['insert'] as $check) {
                $st=$con->prepare("INSERT INTO participants(ID,Name,Handicap) VALUES('$ID','$Name','$Handicap')");
                $insert->bindParam('ID',$ID);
                $insert->bindParam('Name',$Name);
                $insert->bindParam('Handicap',$Handicap);
                $st->execute();
                }
           echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
               alert('Successful Insert ! ');
               window.location.href = 'Add participant.php';
               </script>";
         } else {
           echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('You didn't choose which user you want to insert ! ')</script>";
      }
    }
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "error".$e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not storing the $Name and $Handicap values in the insert[] array, you only storing the $ID value.

To resolve, do something like this:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='insert[]' value='$ID|$Name|$Handicap'>
```

Then:

```
foreach($_POST['insert'] as $check) {
  $values = explode('|', $check);
  $ID = $values[0];
  $Name = $values[1];
  $Handicap = $values[2];
  //The rest of your SQL code goes here as you have it...
  $check = ''; 
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. But it doesn't work. I wonder is it can't take the data from table "member" and store it into table "participants"?

Comment: The way to fix this is to look for the errors that are returned with your queries, what are your errors?

Comment: There is no error showed when I previewed it. It just showed the member data in table form and a button of "Add selected". However the button did not function after I ticked the checkbox and clicked the button Add selected.

Comment: Change your button to this: <input type='submit' value='submit' name='add_btn' id='add_btn'>

Comment: Hi, sorry for disturbing again, there is a problem appeared. When I add 5 persons in 1 time and there is only four person is added to my database table and the another one is repeated with the same person's ID and name. Means that each time I add, there is a person's name is keep repeating. Any help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you $check variable needs to be cleared each time the write to DB is completed. Add this $check = ''; after the DB statements in the foreach loop. This would clear the variable values on each loop.

Comment: Glad I could help. Please accept my answer and upvote it.

Comment: Ya sure! I will. Like this??                                                        
  foreach($_POST['insert'] as $check) {
  $values = explode('|', $check);
  $check = '';                                                                                           
  $ID = $values[0];
  $Name = $values[1];
  $Handicap = $values[2];

Comment: I edited the answer to show how to clear the  $check variable.

Comment: It doesn't work. The same data keep coming out whenever I add.

Comment: You need to check your 1st database call to get the data into the form, there must be duplicated data there, possibly in your database.